# pandas concat/merge columns by loop

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

i got df that look like this:

```
data={"name":["T1","T2","tom","adi"],
  "number":["12","345","345","35"]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
```

and i have for loop that run on part of the column "name" ["T1","tom","adi"]
i get every iteration new DataFrame that look like this

```
data2={"name":["T1"],
  "new":["12"],"year":["1299"],"color":["blue"]}
df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
print(df2)
```

when i try to do concat inside the loop `df= pd.concat([df, df2], axis=1)`
i get the columns [ "new","year","color"]
As many times as the iteration number
I want each column to appear once and no more than once. just like here

```
data2={"name":["T1","T2","tom","adi"],
   "new":["12","nan","45","13"],
   "year":["1299","nan","1982","2000"],
   "color":["blue","nan","red","yellow"]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data2)
print(df)
```

Comment: show us the code for the loop - pretty sure we can get rid of it, and your underlying issue.

Comment: In your for loop, can you loop over Records than on Columns? something like `df.to_dict(orient="records")` ? perhaps, your for loop code is necessary to understand what's the issue.

Comment: What I have written here only simulates my problem and is not identical to my data.
In practice my loop is long and includes an API and working on the DATA.
In any case I created a temporary data structure containing the columns I want and in each iteration I added the information to this df and finally added it to the final table.

I would love to hear a more "correct" way to do this without a temporary table